# How to trigger custom SMS/email on new order in OpenCart?

Tags: php, api, opencart, webhooks

I'm developing API for my app which is a manager app for OpenCart stores. I want the webhook of my API to receive a notification on every order that is placed on a store connected to my app so that I can inform the store-manager via SMS or push notification.

So far, I've been able to achieve most of the managerial tasks since none of it required to interact with the core controllers of the OpenCart. Now, I cannot change the existing controllers but I can add my own controllers and models. I don't have much experience with OpenCart but I do understand the structure. Any suggestions? I couldn't find much except the paid plugins, which are out of scope of this question.

One possible solution I can think of is to ping the OpenCart server of the connected store via my API and log new orders every minute and inform the respective user every time there's change in log from previous minute and next minute.

**Update:**

Another solution I could think of is to extend the library class `Mail` with my custom class so every time a mail is fired for new order, my class will be triggered and my APIs will be notified! This will obviously fail in case someone else changed the library file again. Moreover, changing the library file doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Comment: if you try to understand how orders are created in opencart, you would see that the order record is added to the table even before the checkout is completed. You need to check the model checkout/order.php to see at what condition is the email sent to the customer and user for successful orders. you can make your own controller and implement it, but tbh you will have to change the core because you need to call your own method in the checkout/order.php

Comment: Thanks! I did look at the code and I figured, I could override the existing Mail class since a mail is sent on order complete. But being library file, I shouldn't change it. I'm also looking up for events that I could listen to. Lemme know if you could help with that.

Comment: I am not sure about events :) will let you know if i figure it out

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll have is that different payment gateways will confirm the order has been paid for in different ways, for example PayPal use an IPN request to a callback URL in the PayPal gateway code.

So using a cron to regularly check orders as you suggest is not necessarily a bad solution here.

Comment: How about I change the library Mail class and extend it with my custom class? In that way, every time a 'New order' mail is sent, I'll be notified automatically?

Comment: @Sayed instead of dealing with the mail library, why dont you just call your method in checkout/order model where the mail is actually sent for a new order. I can guide you where to call the method. Seems better than changing the mail.php

Comment: Because I'm developing a third party library for my API to interact with. This library is auto-installed as a part of store-validation. Hence, tampering with one's existing code doesn't seem like a good practice to me. Moreover, I want my code to be isolated and independent. I've been reading about events and they seem like a good approach to me. Shall update the post once I've finalized.